# How to display img inside twig with variable + string concatenate?

Tags: twig, symfony

I have problem for displaying img, i saved images with name of book and now to access them need to concatenate .jpg extension. So my problem is how to concatenate variable and string inside twig template ?

```
<img src="{{ path({{ book.name ~ '.jpg' }}) }}"/>
```

here is full code:

```
  {% for book in books %}
  <a href="{{ path('AppBundle_Book_detailsBook', {'bookId': book.id}) }}"
      class="col-2 white kartica">
      <img src="{{ path({{ book.name }} ~ '.jpg' ) }}"/>

      <h4>
          {{ book.name }}

      </h4>

  </a>
{% else %}
  No books.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is `book.name` actually a file that is maybe stored in your `web/` directory?

Comment: no, i sending list of objects Books, a book.name is name of name of the book, but also name of pictures. so i only need to merge book.name with .jpg

Comment: I see what your code is doing, but in order to display the image `book.name.jpg` it needs to be stored somewhere. Are you possibly using a image bundle or similar? Check your `web/` folder to see if it contains those images you uploaded.

Comment: i made a function:        $imagePath = __DIR__.'/../Resources/images/covers'.$bookName.'.jpg';
       if (!file_exists($imagePath)) {
           var_dump($imagePath);
       }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think this is what you need:

```
<img src="{{ asset( '../app/Resources/images/covers/' ~ book.name ~ '.jpg') }}"/>
```

You might need to adjust the path slightly. Assets start from the `web/` directory. I think you should get the idea.

By the way, thank you for making a detailed post!

Answer (score 0):

Why don´t you try these:

```
<img src="{{ path( book.name ~ '.jpg' ) }}"/>
```